# OxyPlot Graph Not Displaying On Xamarin Forms uwp release mode

Tags: xamarin, uwp, oxyplot

I created a xamarin forms project which is using oxyplot and `Rg.Plugins.Popup` xamarin forms.
However, the graph does not work as excepted. I modified code refer to the [link](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/commit/21b152f8ea38975a80c5e4a82e401a1cf33780a2), but graph not show on UWP .

In addition, I init `Rg.Plugins.Popup` and  `oxyplot` with follow code, I don't know what I doing wrong. Please help. thanks in advance.

in UWP project App.xaml.cs

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());

List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();

 //Now, add in all the assemblies your app uses
                assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.PlotModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.PlotController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.Windows.PlotView).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.PlotView).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PlotViewRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

 try
 {
 Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
 // replaces Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
 }
catch (Exception ex) { }

OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
```

Xamarin forms and oxyplot version is

OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms : 1.1.0-unstable0011

Xamarin.Forms: 4.2.0.709249

Comment: I tested with OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms  1.1.0, it works in release mode for uwp platform. I could not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nico Zhu. You are right. Oxyplot Xamrin 1.1.0 works in uwp release mode. The reason why oxyplot graph not display in my code is that I am using Rg.Plugins.Popup and Oxyplot. Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init is different between that two NuGet Package.

Comment: For Rg.Plugins.Popup, I am using this code "Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());". For Oxyplot, I am using "Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);". If I comment out Rg.Plugins.Popup, Oxyplot works well in uwp release mode. However, when I use both of them, oxyplot not work. Do you have good idea? Thank you

Comment: I solved this problem. I modified List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>(); to List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies().ToList(); . And I deleted Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.GetExtraAssemblies());

Comment: Yep, make sense, you could insert Popup assemblies into `assembliesToInclude` then use them in   `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init` method. I have reply the answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use both of them, you could insert their assemblie in the same list. For more please refer the following.

```
List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();

Popup.Init();
OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PlotViewRenderer.Init();

assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.PlotModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.PlotController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.Windows.PlotView).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.PlotView).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PlotViewRenderer).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
var assemblies = Popup.GetExtraAssemblies();

assembliesToInclude.AddRange(assemblies);
var count = assembliesToInclude.Count;

try
{
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);

}
catch (Exception ex) {

}
```